# Adding video with screen mockup frame in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, mocking, frontend, frame, elementor

[image]

I need to embed the video in the empty screen frame using Elementor page builder. How can I do that?

It has to be added on this empty frame like it's shown up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same answer. My solution was editing the video file, so it has the mockup on the video itself.